# How to determine which event called imageMoved:withEvent:forControlEvents?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've added some targets to a button. They work fine. But in my imageMoved... method, how do I determine which one of the two events fired it? Here is where I added the targets:

```
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```

I saw an example recently where the event is tested in the imageMoved method, something like:

```
if (event == UIControlEventTouchDragExit )
```

but that won't compile. I'm not finding any examples online nor any clues in UIControl Class Reference.

What I'm trying to do with this is store the original location of the button/image so that if the user doesn't complete the drag to a target it will snap back to where it came from.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different methods

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withDragInsideEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withDragExitEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```

and reuse common functionality in 3rd method.

Comment: That totally works! thanks! In the process of implementing and testing I realized that what I really wanted was withTouchUpInsideEvent and not withDragExitEvent, but your solution works great with my amended code. (For anyone other newb who stumbles onto this, withDragExitEvent refers to "An event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside its bounds." What I needed to know was When has the user stopped dragging and lifted her finger.)